How can we use 4 HTC Vive controllers with No HMD Vive Wireless Dongle?
We have a project, where we are using NO HMD and only steam VR and HTC vive trackers. We want to switch to the HTC vive controllers with these vive dongles. We can connect 4 Controller with dongles but we can just get input from just 2 of the controller as Left Hand and Right Hand role from OpenVR API class and other controllers shows up as Invalid. Here below is the open vr api classes, 2 of them also shows up as EtrackedDevicelass = controller but other are invalid.
Thank you and any help would be appreciated.
public enum ETrackedDeviceClass
{
    Invalid = 0,
    HMD = 1,
    Controller = 2,
    GenericTracker = 3,
    TrackingReference = 4,
    DisplayRedirect = 5,
    Max = 6,
}
public enum ETrackedControllerRole
{
    Invalid = 0,
    LeftHand = 1,
    RightHand = 2,
    OptOut = 3,
    Treadmill = 4,
    Stylus = 5,
    Max = 5,
}

